# neo4j heroku hosting

Tags: graph, heroku, neo4j

I have a web application deployed on heroku. 
I just introduced Neo4j as data structure and, of course, I have to integrate it in production on heroku. I read on this link http://wiki.neo4j.org/content/Neo4j_Heroku_Addon that the heroku addon for neo4j is currently on beta testing.
 So have looked for alternative ways and I found this link: http://wiki.neo4j.org/content/Neo4j_in_the_Cloud ... do you know if it's possible to include such integration on heroku without the addon ?
Tnx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are a registered [beta tester](http://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/support) on heroku you can already use the [add-on](http://addons.heroku.com/neo4j) for free.

Of course if you want to run the Neo4j REST server on your own aws ec2 instances you can do that easily (there are also preconfigured [AMI's](http://jussiheinonen.blogspot.com/2011/05/neo4j-graph-database-server-image-in.html)). Please make sure that your ec2 instances run in the aws us-east region as this is where heroku's machines are located too.

Comment: [Disclaimer: I'm of the founders of [GrapheneDB](http://www.graphenedb.com).]
The add-on by Neo Technology has been discontinued but you can use the [GrapheneDB Heroku add-on](https://addons.heroku.com/graphenedb), which offers free and paid Neo4j instances, depending on your requirements.

Comment: [GrapheneDB Heroku Add-On is no longer available](https://docs.graphenedb.com/docs/shutdown-of-heroku-add-on) as of 14 January 2021 and [GrapheneDB has removed the free Hobby plan](https://www.graphenedb.com/blog/2020/09/10/new-plans/) as of 26 January 2021. Dedicated paid hosting is still available as per usual, with 2 weeks free trials currently.